# Intercept and capture response value

Tags: java, rx-java

I have this RxJava code:

```
User user; 

public Single<User> login(String username, String password) {
    return userRepository.login(username, password);
}
```

I want to know how can the response `User` can be intercepted and assigned in a local variable.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#hello-world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html):

```
User user; 

public Single<User> login(String username, String password) {
    return userRepository
               .login(username, password)
               .map((User u) -> {
                   user = u;
                   return u;
               });
}
```